# Is auto-fellatio haram?

Tags: halal-haram, masturbation

I am 15, and I sometimes have a very very high gaze, and I used to watch porn. However, I no longer watch porn (Alhamdullilah). These days I sometimes lick my own penis, but I make sure not to ejaculate. I sometimes wrap a pillow around my penis and move it gently to lower my gaze. Again I make sure not to ejaculate. Is this considered as haram?

Comment: I don't think ejaculation is necessary for masturbation to be considered haram; I'm not completely sure though. Either way, auto-fellatio would definitely be considered masturbation.

Comment: What does _"to have a very high gaze"_ mean?

Comment: In other words, I have high libido

Comment: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/3004/masturbation-and-islam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is very haram! You are still stimulating yourself outside of marriage, and the only sexual actions you may commit are with your wife, and even that is strictly vaginal. This helps to calm and limit sexual desire and drive outside of that bond, and the like. You must try your best to stop it now! It's so, so bad for you. It's quite sinful.

Repent by doing wudhu and praying two rakat nafl immediately, if you haven't already. You will feel much better.

Good that you've gotten off of pornography, brother. Hopefully, Allah will guide you to the path of purity. ^ ^

Comment: That's you my brother for this response, once I asked this question I stopped doing it till I get a response. I really thank God for helping me to stop pornography. I am going to do my best to stop that.

Comment: "and even that is strictly vaginal" - the scholars who say that oral is haram seem to be a minority.