# Is anal masturbation haram?

Tags: halal-haram, masturbation

I finally stopped masturbation and watching porn, but I sometimes get really really aroused. I don't want to do anything haram. Is anal masturbation haram?

Comment: the whole purpose of the "path of God" is to rise beyond the animal that is inside you.

Comment: Please stop asking such questions. I think it is quite clear that certain things things are forbidden. ASK your own conscience... you know that it's not good but you just ask in order to get probable justifications to your actions. Earlier you asked about auto fellatio.... Brother lets cease to do such acts and ask questions through which we canget closer and closer to Allah swt

Comment: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/3004/masturbation-and-islam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In simple, masturbation of all kinds will have same ruling.

And anal sex is forbidden with priority anyway. So, there is nothing complicated to clear about.

Anal sex is haram, and same ruling of masturbation on all of its kinds.

Comment: Well, it's easy to throw a halal or haram here and there. People still miss the concept of the "Way of God" that the Quran preaches.

Comment: Quran declares anal sex haram... i am not THROWING it

Comment: Quran hints anal sex is not the way that God preaches. God doesn't go into ridiculous details that are the fruit of human pervesities. Of course you can still throw a haram to them. The point is if an activity is the fruit of a perversity/transgression of the human kind, throwing a haram is irrelevant. The problem is that they lost the "Path of God". This is just a small remark. by the way I think he is trolling. for the second time.

Comment: Although this is not the topic of this post, but i should tell you about the consensus at-least among ahlul sunnah on anal sex being haraam.