# Is it a sin for a woman to look at her private parts, etc., for arousal?

Tags: halal-haram, sexuality

This is a question of my friend. If she's arousing herself sexually by looking at her private parts, by looking in the mirror of her naked self and by adding things to her private parts, would it be considered a sin? She's not reaching her climax. She's just arousing herself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is masturbation permissible for a man during an extended period of unmarried life?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/3004/is-masturbation-permissible-for-a-man-during-an-extended-period-of-unmarried-lif)

Comment: @Uma but here she's not masturbating. She's not reaching her climax, she stops before it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Yes, it is a sin

---

Many scholars may (Allah have mercy upon them) are of the view that it is disliked for a person to look at his private parts and some of them have even forbidden it.

> Al-Hattaab may  Allaah  have  mercy  upon  him from the Maaliki school, said:
>
> [In relation to a person looking to his own private parts without a necessity, Ibn Al-Qattaan (may Allah have mercy upon him) said that there are two opinions, one is that it is disliked and the other is that it is forbidden.
>
> At-Tirmithi may  Allaah  have  mercy  upon  him said: 'If a person does this regularly, he will be afflicted with fornication or adultery.']
>
> Moreover, Al-Mardaawi (may Allah have mercy upon him) from the Hanbali school, said: 'It is disliked to look at one's own private parts …, one should not look at it as this is a sign of vileness and despicability.'

So a person should not look at their own private parts in the mirror or directly without a necessity, **but there is no evidence that says that it is forbidden so it is at least makruh.**

---

You said:

> This is a question of my friend. If she's arousing herself sexually by looking at her private parts, by looking in the mirror of her naked self and by adding things to her private parts, would it be considered a sin? She's not reaching her climax. She's just arousing herself.

As stated above, it is makruh to look at your self naked in the mirror.

**So you might be asking how is it a sin because at the top I said it was a sin?**

---

It **is a sin** because:

Allah says in the Qu'ran:

> "And those who guard their chastity (i.e. private parts, from **illegal sexual acts**). Except from their wives or (the captives and slaves) that their right hands possess, - for them, they are free from blame. But whoever seeks beyond that, then those are the transgressors."
>
> ([23:5-7](https://quran.com/23/5-7))

Also the Prophet Muhammad said:

> Abdullaah ibn Mas’ood said, "We were with the Prophet while we were young and had no wealth whatsoever. So Allaah’s Messenger said, "O young people! Whoever among you can marry, should marry, because it helps him lower his gaze and guard his modesty (i.e. his private parts from committing **illegal sexual acts** etc.), and whoever is not able to marry, should fast, as fasting diminishes his sexual power."
>
> Narrated in Bukhari (5066)

The above verse and hadith clearly states that looking at yourself naked for sexual arousal is trangressing making it haram **and a sin**.

And Allah knows best.

---

Source: [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/329) and [IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=83076)

Comment: Can someone explain the down vote please?

Comment: The headline contradicts the body "but there is no evidence that says that it is forbidden so it is at least makruh."

Comment: The first part of my body is saying that looking in general at your private parts is Makruh, the second part of my body is the looking at your private part for sexual arousal is a sin so the headline and body don't contradict.

Answer (score 0):

Arousing oneself by adding things to the private parts is masterbation, even if orgasm was not achieved. So it is a sin at that. The act of arousing oneself by looking in mirror would be haram in itself.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is necessary in needed situations
But if you are a Muslim and arousing yourself like that...and in addition you added that looking at private parts and adding things to it...so if you are a Muslim you know about the devil(shaytan)...i don't mean this as perfect masturbation...but according to Islam devil is trying to make everyone of us to do sins...he won't make everyone do sins directly at that spot...he will proceed to steps after steps and slowly eventually will lead to sin...the person won't even realize...it's not a complete sexual act but partial but this could also be a sign that devil just now targeted you...it's better to stop at the first stage
Thank you
Assalamu alaikum

Answer (score -4):

As-Salaam alaykum... i disagree. 
    It's apparent to me that both the Qur'anic ayat and the hadith are speaking from a social context, or in the public sphere, i.e., as a member of society.
   But, on the private or personal level, that is, in the privacy of yr home, alone, i don't think Allah (swt) is saying, it's sinful.
   I believe this "sinful" interpretation of the shaykh comes from the Hellenistic and Christian traditions in Western civilization.
   Muslims shd look at genitals as sacred tools from Allah, and not as dirty, lustful, haraam organs of the body.