# Is ghusl (bath) mandatory after masturbation?

Tags: sex, ghusl, masturbation

Assalamualaikum everyone
Is it compulsory to bath after masturbation?
Or only washing the penis (awrah) will do ?

Comment: Ghusl doesn’t mean necessary “bath”, it also means “shower”

Comment: I didn't understand tell me clearly do I have to bath after masturbation to do my prayers? @AlexA

Comment: Yes of course you need to do that. But you need to make sure that you stop masturbate also unless you really think you'd commit zina otherwise I was told by a source.

Comment: Read this question for more information about whether or not masturbation is allowed.  https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/3004/is-masturbation-permissible-for-a-man-during-an-extended-period-of-unmarried-lif

Answer (score -1):

Assalamu alaikum brother.

Its really nice to see your concern for purity.

The answer to your question would be that you must have the obligatory bath which you probably know how to do.

However you should also **keep in mind that masturbation is better to avoid**. I think it's explicitly harm according to some Islamic scholars.

Wassalam