# Sexual life in islam

Tags: halal-haram, masturbation

masturbate once a week as not having sex with my wife from the last five years. Is it allowed in Islam, and what effect will it have on my health?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is masturbation permissible for a man during an extended period of unmarried life?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/3004/is-masturbation-permissible-for-a-man-during-an-extended-period-of-unmarried-lif) there are about 100 questions on this topic already on the site and thousands on the web.

Comment: You havent had sex with your wife for the past 5 years? I dont want to get into the personal side of things but is it due to health problems? This may help to get a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Anything which is unnatural is haram in Islam. Men and women have been given an ability to meet each other need in legal way, specially when you are married.

Here are views of Dr Zakir Naik, renowned Muslim Scholar,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1DtNKU25ejY