# Can i pull out and quickly masturbate to ejaculate while having sex with my wife

Tags: sex

SEX WITH WIFE AND MASTURBATING

I want to know if its okay if i pull out while having sex with my wife and then i quickly masturbate to ejaculate. I have done it before but i don’t really know if i can and i don’t want to get sins
I have searched this up many times but I haven’t gotten an answer and I'm really curious if i can. And this will help other people incase they want to know

Comment: What should this be good for? Why don't you let your wife do it that would be regarded as acceptable?

Comment: Im talking about like doggystyle then i pull out to ejaculate but i masturbate to do it

Comment: I have answered a very similar question here https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/75210/can-i-masturbate-after-practicing-azl-with-my-wife-if-i-cant-ejaculate-naturall

Comment: Also doggystyle and any other anal sex is totally haram

Comment: Self masturbation is haram, especially since you are married and do not fear Zina. If needed you can have your wife masturbate you with her hands etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is masturbation permissible for a man during an extended period of unmarried life?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/3004/is-masturbation-permissible-for-a-man-during-an-extended-period-of-unmarried-lif)

Answer (score -1):

depends if you are penetrating from anal or vaginal either way masturbation is haram and considered a sin if you where to pull out as you where about to release your fluids however it would be okay

Answer (score -1):

Pulling out which is called al azl in Arabic was discouraged by Prophet.

In one case when muslims went & captured women to keep them as concubines(sex slaves), his followers were hesitant to make them pregnant. so when asked to prophet, he clearly discouraged idea of al-azl. He didn't want his followers to pull out from captive women(sex slaves).

So prophet discouraged pulling out from sex slaves why would he wanted husbands to pull out from their wives? Logically it doesn't make sense? Isn't it ?

Reference for hadith in [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1438a)
https://sunnah.com/muslim:1438a

*0 Abu Sa'id, did you hear Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) mentioning al-'azl? He said: Yes, and added: We went out with Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) on the expedition to the Bi'l-Mustaliq and took captive some excellent Arab women; and we desired them, for we were suffering from the absence of our wives, (but at the same time) we also desired ransom for them. So we decided to have sexual intercourse with them but by observing 'azl (Withdrawing the male sexual organ before emission of semen to avoid-conception). But we said: We are doing an act whereas Allah's Messenger is amongst us; why not ask him? So we asked Allah's Mes- senger (ﷺ), and he said: It does not matter if you do not do it, for every soul that is to be born up to the Day of Resurrection will be born.*