# Can I masturbate after practicing Azl with my wife if I can't ejaculate naturally?

Tags: fiqh, husband-wife, masturbation, sexuality

Salam 'Alaykoum,

I am currently married and practice interrupted coitus ('azl), I withdraw before ejaculation to avoid pregnancy.

The problem is that when I withdraw I have to stimulate my genital organ a bit by going back and forth with my hand to be able to ejaculate outside (which is in a way a masturbation that I do for a few seconds to ejaculate).

What is the status of this practice? If this is not allowed, how can I practice interrupted coitus by ejaculating outside since I have to stimulate it a bit to ejaculate at the end of the intercourse.

BarakAllahufikum

Comment: Well Dr. Zakir Naik says mastrurbation isn't haram aslong as you are doing it with your spouse. So I think its okay.

Comment: @muslimpro56 Yes, that each one does it to the other is indeed allowed, but here it is a question of doing it myself that is different no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The act of masturbation is haram, mostly because of the things it can lead to like zina. However, as you are currently fulfilling sexual pleasure with your wife, it should be okay.

Also, if you are unable to ejaculate after performing interrupted coitus without more stimulation the best option would be for your spouse to perform the act for you instead as it will fulfil her sexual pleasure too.

Comment: Yes BarakAllahufik, you have answered the question (which was whether this "masturbation" of a few seconds after the interrupted coitus was haram since I am the one doing it)

Comment: but even if this solution is possible, is this practice that I am doing haram?

Comment: Well, this is a Q&A site. An answer should be an answer, not just an advice.

Comment: Sorry I will edit it

Comment: Please provide adequate daleel/proof/evidence. Mere opinions are not enough and it can lead to misunderstanding.

Comment: These are not opinions but maslah I have been taught by muftis

Comment: What is the difference? This is definitely an opinion. There are different scholarly opinions regarding issues.

Comment: @userNameAsString Thank you for your answer, but in order to be sure I would like to know if you have a particular source? It doesn't matter if it's a video, a fatwa, a passage from a fiqh book or even the teaching of one of your professors if you can give me their name and/or their obedience so that I can get an idea, do you understand me?

Comment: @Elblocktri I have cited from an aalim but I refuses to disclose his name as he is my teacher and if I have made a mistake, I don't want the sin to go on him too.

Comment: @userNameAsString No problem, I would just like to know his obedience and if he teaches according to a fiqh school

Comment: @Elblocktri Sorry, it is according to the Hanafi school. I forgot to mention that