# Being LGBTQ+ in Islam

Tags: fiqh, homosexuality

I read an answer to a question that said that being gay in Islam isn’t a problem but if you do gay actions that’s where the problem is (that was the basis of it it’s not the exact statement).

Gay relationships/sex has been observed by scientists to occur naturally in even animals and it isn’t a choice. I’ve heard that there are those who oppose this but the evidence backing up is incomparable to the former.

Straight people can get married to women/men and relive their sexual desires through their sexual partners. However, what if a gay/lesbian Muslim can’t get married what can they do? It’s equally as hard to control their natural inclination to relieve sexual distress. Are they allowed to masturbate so they don’t end up fornicating or for their sexual desires since they can’t marry or have sex?

Comment: Also I have tried looking for information on this topic but it is very limited. Weren’t there any homosexuals in the company of the prophet and didn’t the prophet teach anything about it?

Answer (score 3):

More generally it should be said having the inclination or desire to commit a sin isn't sinful in and of itself and actually making actions is sinful.

The position of a homosexual person who cannot get married is not inherently different from the position of a normal person who, due to a variety of reasons, cannot get married.

For both of them is patience and perseverance. As you said, it is equally hard for them. It is not impossible in any way for them to refrain from haram. Desire is not something that forces you. It is something that inclines you, but you can choose to refrain.

The Prophet (SAW) advised unmarried people to fast to lessen their urges.

As for masturbation, you can see the question here: [Is masturbation permissible for a man during an extended period of unmarried life?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/3004/is-masturbation-permissible-for-a-man-during-an-extended-period-of-unmarried-lif)

The answer applies to a homosexual person as much as it applies to others.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking or stating your opinion?

Sodomy is prohibited for everyone. And there are restrictions on who you can marry and have sex with for everyone.

I don't think LGBTQ+ has anything to do with Islam.
It's like asking which football team, or which superhero, or which car is best according to Islam. Maybe opinions about LGBTQ+ belongs in an other forum.