# I accidently ejactulated during my fast- is it broken?

Tags: sawm, ramadan

So i am a teenager and have problems with masturbation - i accidentally ejactulated semen when i did not mean to (i knew it would break my fast if i did) - If i accidentally did it, would my fast be broken?

I didn’t do it intentionally, i only meant that to masturbate and i tried to prevent it before ejactulating but it just happened- If i did break my fast , i cannot fast for 60 days (me and my family plan on traveling during May-June) and I can’t feed 60 homeless people (I don’t really know where to feed them and my parents don’t let me donate to food drives)

Comment: If you masturbate, of course you will ejaculate, thus breaking your fast. But you don't have to fast for 60 days or feed people, because masturbation is not considered as sexual intercourse.

Comment: @Yusha any evidence for that? And which school of jurisprudence are you representing in your comment?

Comment: @MediSaif Al mughni by ibn qudamah Three stroke 156. Also [Here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/38943/35781) Brother UmH here shows that one of the views of hanafi that masturbation is not considered as sexual intercourse. also it is known that there is difference of opinion about masturbation being haram.

Comment: @Medi1Saif and i assume that you are asking for the evidence about masturbation not being sexual intercourse. becz I am not sure about the part that he can or cannot continue fasting. But i think his fast cannot not be continued And he needs to make up for that fast

Comment: It doesn't make sense to speak of accident if you know that masturbation is discouraged and did it. @Yusha even if a fast is broken it must be continued beside the kaffarah etc. ,.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I wasn't talking about the whole month, if that's what you mean. I am saying he can't continue that particular fast in that single day.

Comment: @Yusha No I mean he must continue his day fasting. If you have an evidence for a contrary view that would be new to me

Comment: @Medi1Saif I mean he ejaculated. One of the things that break fast