# Masturbation/Haram

Tags: masturbation

I masturbated beside my ex friends child while she was sleeping and I was told it is Haram and is unforgivable  please tell me that is not true. I'm so scared. The mother destroyed my relationship with my ex boyfriend & she's determined to keep us apart. What do I do? Her husband is Muslim. Just to clarify I was not masturbating in a sexual way. I was just trying to help myself to sleep. I have been on antidepressants for many years & I believe I have suffered some brain damage from them. They are very dangerous.

Comment: Is nobody going to respond please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will Allah forgive me for doing X ? (reference question)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/71337/will-allah-forgive-me-for-doing-x-reference-question)

Comment: Also see [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/3004/) for the ruling on masturbation.

Comment: I don't think you will get good answers here as it is related Islamic psychology and I don't think there are experts in this field here.

Comment: Ok so where should I ask this question then please? Did I deserve to lose my ex boyfriend over it?

Comment: if you masturbate with something in your mind only without doing any harm, it is just like dream only. In my opinion you don't deserve to lose your ex boy friend.

Comment: Hi shafeek thank you for your response. can we talk on private message please?  because I really need help. I'm really suffering here & I'm very confused about what happened. When I masturbated beside the child I wasn't thinking about anything really, I believe I was thinking about wanting to sleep. I was not thinking about my ex boyfriend at all or thinking about sex or anything sexual. Not thinking lustfully or anything. The mother must think that I was though correct? That is why she won't let me have him back. Also I did not harm the child in any way. I hope she didn't see me.

Answer (score 1):

Allah forgives all kinds of sins, as stated in this verse:

> قُلۡ يَٰعِبَادِيَ ٱلَّذِينَ أَسۡرَفُواْ عَلَىٰٓ أَنفُسِهِمۡ لَا
> تَقۡنَطُواْ مِن رَّحۡمَةِ ٱللَّهِۚ إِنَّ ٱللَّهَ يَغۡفِرُ ٱلذُّنُوبَ
> جَمِيعًاۚ إِنَّهُۥ هُوَ ٱلۡغَفُورُ ٱلرَّحِيمُ 53
>
> (VI) SAY: "My servants who have acted extravagantly against themselves
> still do not despair of God's mercy. God forgives all sins; He is
> the Forgiving, the Merciful. [(53)](https://quran.inoor.ir/en/ayah/39/53/)

But it is needed to do Tawbah and leave the sin.

> يَـٰٓأَيُّهَا ٱلَّذِينَ ءَامَنُواْ تُوبُوٓاْ إِلَى ٱللَّهِ تَوۡبَةٗ
> نَّصُوحًا عَسَىٰ رَبُّكُمۡ أَن يُكَفِّرَ عَنكُمۡ سَيِّـَٔاتِكُمۡ
> وَيُدۡخِلَكُمۡ جَنَّـٰتٖ تَجۡرِي مِن تَحۡتِهَا ٱلۡأَنۡهَٰرُ يَوۡمَ لَا
> يُخۡزِي ٱللَّهُ ٱلنَّبِيَّ وَٱلَّذِينَ ءَامَنُواْ مَعَهُۥۖ نُورُهُمۡ
> يَسۡعَىٰ بَيۡنَ أَيۡدِيهِمۡ وَبِأَيۡمَٰنِهِمۡ يَقُولُونَ رَبَّنَآ
> أَتۡمِمۡ لَنَا نُورَنَا وَٱغۡفِرۡ لَنَآۖ إِنَّكَ عَلَىٰ كُلِّ شَيۡءٖ
> قَدِيرٞ 8
>
> (II) You who believe, turn to God in frank repentance. Perhaps your
> Lord will remit your evil deeds for you and show you into gardens
> through which rivers flow, on a day when God will not let the Prophet
> be humiliated. Those who believe will stand alongside him, their light
> streaming on ahead of them and to their right. They will say: " Our
> Lord, perfect our light for us, and forgive us! You are Capable of
> everything!" [(8)](https://quran.inoor.ir/en/ayah/66/8/)

Also having boyfriend is Haram in Islam:

> وَمَن لَّمۡ يَسۡتَطِعۡ مِنكُمۡ طَوۡلًا أَن يَنكِحَ ٱلۡمُحۡصَنَٰتِ
> ٱلۡمُؤۡمِنَٰتِ فَمِن مَّا مَلَكَتۡ أَيۡمَٰنُكُم مِّن فَتَيَٰتِكُمُ
> ٱلۡمُؤۡمِنَٰتِۚ وَٱللَّهُ أَعۡلَمُ بِإِيمَٰنِكُمۚ بَعۡضُكُم مِّنۢ
> بَعۡضٖۚ فَٱنكِحُوهُنَّ بِإِذۡنِ أَهۡلِهِنَّ وَءَاتُوهُنَّ أُجُورَهُنَّ
> بِٱلۡمَعۡرُوفِ مُحۡصَنَٰتٍ غَيۡرَ مُسَٰفِحَٰتٖ وَلَا مُتَّخِذَٰتِ
> أَخۡدَانٖۚ فَإِذَآ أُحۡصِنَّ فَإِنۡ أَتَيۡنَ بِفَٰحِشَةٖ
> فَعَلَيۡهِنَّ نِصۡفُ مَا عَلَى ٱلۡمُحۡصَنَٰتِ مِنَ ٱلۡعَذَابِۚ ذَٰلِكَ
> لِمَنۡ خَشِيَ ٱلۡعَنَتَ مِنكُمۡۚ وَأَن تَصۡبِرُواْ خَيۡرٞ لَّكُمۡۗ
> وَٱللَّهُ غَفُورٞ رَّحِيمٞ 25
>
> And whosoever of you who has Not the means to marry free-believing
> Women, may marry believing girls From among those [captives and
> Slaves] whom you own; and Allāh is The Knower of your Faith; you are
> Fellow-creatures; then, wed them with The permission of their own folk
> [Guardians or masters] and give them Their marriage-portion according
> To what is reasonable, provided That they are chaste, not adulterous
> Nor taking **boyfriends**; and after they Have been taken in wedlock, if
> they Commit adultery, their punishment is Half of that for a free
> woman. This [type Of marriage] is for those men among you Who are
> afraid of committing sin of Adultery [due to physical need], but it is
> Better for you to practice self-restraint, And Allāh is the Merciful
> Forgiving; [(25)](https://quran.inoor.ir/en/ayah/4/25/)

Comment: Why is having a boyfriend Haram? Thats not fair. 

Comment: @KatherineForan it is command of Allah. also a boyfriend can easily leave girl and find another without paying any rights or having any duties. but husband have to pay different rights and has many duties against the woman and the rights of woman is respected in marriage.

Comment: Where in the Bible does it say it's the command of Allah? :'( I think it's ridiculous & unfair for it to be Haram to have a boyfriend.

Comment: @KatherineForan this is Islam site. not Christianity.

Comment: Yeah I know that.  Oh so in the quran it says it's Haram to have a boyfriend?

Comment: @KatherineForan yes. according to the verse in my answer.

Comment: I really don't think that is fair  there's nothing wrong with having a boyfriend. I don't understand this.