# Is it haram for a single man to use a sex toy

Tags: sex

I am a man and not married is it considered zina if i use a sex toy that looks like a female organ and insert my private parts in it? Jazakallah I really want to no I don’t want to do zina.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is masturbation permissible for a man during an extended period of unmarried life?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/3004/is-masturbation-permissible-for-a-man-during-an-extended-period-of-unmarried-lif)

Answer (score -1):

It is considered masturbation and it is haram in Islam for both men and women to masturbate, except only if they fear they will do Zina, if they not satisfie themselves. That is what most scholars believe. And Allah knows best.

Answer (score -1):

No I don't think it's haram cuz it's 1st musturbation 2nd musturbation isn't haram

Comment: If some children find this toy, wouldn't that mislead them ?

Answer (score -1):

masturbation Is haram in Islam said it is not allowed before or after marriage